# Armazenar parte de uma string em uma variável

Tags: c#, .net, string

Recebo a *string* abaixo, através de um `response.StreamReader`:

```
240144|000|5511946724649|2015-08-30 21:45:51|2015-08-30 21:46:02|1|
```

Como devo proceder para armazenar o conteúdo entre os pipes cada um em uma variável?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#overloads):

```
var items = texto.Split('|');
```

Isto gerará um *array*, se quiser pegue cada elemento e coloque em cada variável que deseja. Isto é um trabalho manual mesmo.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ExdV2b). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4EDiqp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Split2.cs).